# Delete rows from parent table after deleting multiple children SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, not-exists, notin

I have a table that has foreign key in 4 other tables. I deleted the rows in the children tables and in order to delete from the parent, I do a query where not exist, since I have deleted the references. But I still have an issue on writing the query since it returns an empty result set.

I believe I do something wrong.

Here is my query

```
select *
from paretntable 
where parentID not in (select i.ParentID 
                       from child1 i 
                       left join child2 m on i.parentID = m.parentID) 
  and not exists (select ac.parentID 
                  from child3 ac 
                  left join child4 d on ac.parentID = d.parentID)
```

Comment: If you're deleting the children to delete the parent(s) why not, instead, enable cascading and just delete the parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
so, I set up two tables... ParentTable with a key of ParentID, 
and ChildTable, key of ChildID and FK of ParentID.


delete dbo.parenttable
where parentid = 3
-- produces error because rows exist in dbo.childtable where parentid = 3

delete dbo.childtable 
where parentid = 3
-- deletes all rows in dbo.childtable where parentid = 3

-- Assuming This is where you are now
--- .... needing to find all rows in parent table 
---      where there are no corresponding child 
---      rows in dbo.childtable


with CTE_Parent as          --wrap up the selected ID's in a CTE expression
(select dbo.parenttable.parentid
from dbo.parenttable
left outer join dbo.childtable 
on dbo.parenttable.parentid = dbo.childtable.parentid   
where dbo.childtable.parentid is null  --- trick to find non-existent child recs
)

delete dbo.parenttable
from dbo.parenttable
inner join cte_Parent
on dbo.parenttable.parentid = cte_parent.parentid
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it, left join to all the children and then check to see if they are all null (in this case I use coalesce to do so.)  This is very efficient and uses all indexes you have set up in your tables.  It does not have any sub-queries.

```
select *
from paretntable p
left join child1 i on p.parentID =  i.parentID
left join child2 m on p.parentID =  m.parentID
left join child3 ac on p.parentID =  ac.parentID
left join child4 d on p.parentID =  d.parentID
where coalesce(i.parentID, m.parentID, ac.parenti, d.parentID) is null
```